# limit infimum and limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

If we know $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_{n}(x) = f(x)$, what can we say about $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \inf f_{n}(x)$? Is it equal to $f(x)$? If not, what is their relationshiop?

Comment: $\inf f_{n} (x)$ is constant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean limit inferior instead of limit infimum, they are equal. For every $x$, $(f_n(x))_n$ is a sequence. When a sequence has a limit, than limit is equal to the liminf (and equal to the limsup), so $\text{liminf}_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = f(x).$

If you mean the limit for $n\to \infty$ of the infimum of the set $\{f_k(x)\}_k,$ then, as someone else already pointed out, that would just be the limit of a constant sequence. This limit would equal $\inf_n f_n(x),$ but I don't believe that this makes any sense.